# Azure Devops YAML Pipeline Trigger not firing for branches with forward slash

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm attempting to trigger a pipeline when another pipeline in the same repository completed. This works for the main branch but fails to trigger for branches that have a forward slash in the branch name '/'

The documentation says this is valid

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: sample value
    source: sample value
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main
        - sample/branch/*
```

I expect this to trigger for branches like the following: sample/branch/myNewFeature, but it doesn't. Any similar issues?

Comment: Are the "sample value" strings after the pipeline: and source: labels real or just placeholders for your SO question?

Comment: @JohnH They're placeholders for the question, I've confirmed the real values I'm using work for the main branch (so are correct :) )

Answer (score 0):

Testing in my side and found that if corresponding yaml file is not stored in this `sample/branch/myNewFeature` branch, and then the pipeline will not be triggered from this branch.

In other words, you need to copy the target yaml file to the triggered branch, so the related yaml pipeline can be triggered.

See: [Trigger one pipeline after another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) for more details.

**Update**>>
[image]

Comment: Hi Edward! Thank you for your attention and reply. The YAML is stored in both the `main` branch and the `sample/branch/myNewFeature` branch.

Comment: If you manually trigger this target pipeline from  the ```sample/branch/myNewFeature``` branch, will it run? In addition, please edit the target pipeline and check its Triggers settings to find whether it configure build completion triggers in the UI, which will affect pipeline resource triggers. This has been noted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops.